# Is there an equivalent of a shortcut or mklink in files between teams channels in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

I noticed we were creating duplicate files for multiple channels within a Teams Team, and it seems it would make more sense to store one file with a bunch of shortcuts pointing at it in the various groups since the content isn't any different.

Does SharePoint have an equivalent to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some files that all teams need to work on, then it would be better to create a SharePoint site or library that all these teams have access to. They can then collaborate on the same files, stored in that site.

Comment: They are all on the same Team; I mean is it possible to have the same file shared between different channels?  It's annoying to update more than one just because a copy of the file is in multiple channels.

Comment: Just store those the files in one channel? e.g. the General channel. You could also just create another tab in each channel which shows the Team's SharePoint library.

Comment: Do you mean a tab that displays the Teams files that are really stored in SharePoint (like the SharePoint website)?  

Also, isn't there a way to map the SharePoint files as though they are a shared drive?  Would `mklink` work in there?

Comment: All Microsoft Teams files are stored in SharePoint Online. A tab in each channel pointing to your Team's document library would work or the team could just use the General channel for files which are relevant across many channels. Using SharePoint libraries like shared drives is not really advisable anymore, better to use Teams or OneDrive for Business to sync the library to your machine.